# $\mathfrak{p}$-adic topology and the symbolic power topology

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm studying symbolic powers from "Singularities and Foliations. Geometry, Topology and Applications".

The $n$th symbolic power of the ideal $I$ in a Noetherian domain $R$, is defined by $I^{(n)}= \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\in Ass_R(R/I)}(I^nR_{\mathfrak{p}}\cap R)$.

"There is a linear relationship between the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic topology and the symbolic power topology of the prime $\mathfrak{p}$: There exists a constant $h$ such that for all $n$, $\mathfrak{p}^{(hn)}\subset\mathfrak{p}^n$."

I couldn't find the definition of $\mathfrak{p}$-adic topology and the symbolic power topology of the prime $\mathfrak{p}$. If anyone introduces any reference that has defined them I would be really thankful

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Adic_topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any filtration (a descending chain) of ideals induces a topology on $R$. A basis for this topology is given by all translates of ideals appearing in the filtration. So, if our filtration is $\{I_i\}$, then the open basis consists of sets of the form $a+I_i$ for any $a \in R$ and any $i$. If $I$ is any ideal, one defines the $I$-adic filtration to be $\{I^n\}$ and the $I$-adic topology is the topology induced by this filtration. The Symbolic power topology considers instead the topology induced by the filtration $\{I^{(n)}\}$ of symbolic powers of $I$.